# Is it possible to get Google Calendar working within an iOS app?

Tags: ios, iframe, cordova, google-calendar-api

I have spent ages trying to figure this out..

I have google calendar loaded into an iframe using this code from google calendar:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;mode=AGENDA&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=cymraegioedolion%40googlemail.com&amp;color=%23A32929&amp;ctz=Europe%2FLondon" style=" border-width:0 " width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

It works fine on the website http://m.welshforadults.cardiff.ac.uk/activities.html and when I run the website on the iPhone, but the client now wants me to convert this website to an app - I have decided to use Phonegap / Cordova for this (version 3.3.0).

I have everything working, but this calendar page.

It just lodes nothing in the content screen as you can see below:

[image]

I read up about possible problems and there seems to be a few issues with iframes, but I couldn't find any other ways to solve this issue..

Cheers for taking a look!

Comment: The Calendar/iframe loads fine for me with PG 3.2. I just had to make sure to have an `<access origin="https://www.google.com" />` in my config.xml.

Comment: That solved the problem thank you! Now to fix the styling problems ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to add the following line into the config.xml:

```
<access origin="https://www.google.com" />
```

Thanks to [Uncharted Space](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1901416/uncharted-space).